# Splitting audio on a PC with a multiple screen setup

Tags: windows-8.1, audio, multiple-monitors

I have 2 samsung pc monitors with build in speakers. What I want to do is play 2 different videos with one PC. One video on the first Samsung PC monitor and another video on the second samsung PC monitor. But on screen one the audio of video 1 and 2 plays and vice versa. Is there a possibility to split the audio over the PC monitors, so that the first screen only plays the audio of the first video and vice versa.

The first screen is connected with HDMI, the second one is connected with DVI. And the screens have a green input for a headphone.

**PC :**

```
MSI R4870-T2D512-OC 512MB GDDR5 PCI EXPRESS
SAMSUNG HD753LJ 750GB 32MB SATA300 7200RPM
INTEL CORE 2 DUO E8500 45NM 3.16 SOCKET 775
ASUS P5K-E WIFI SOCKET 775 INTEL® P35
PREMIUM 2GB (1X2GB) 800MHZ
SAMSUNG SH-S223F/BEBE ZWART SATA 22X DVD-RW
OCZ 600WATT GAMEXSTREAM POWER SUPPLY
ANTEC P182 BLACK PERFORMANCE CASE
```

So do I need a secondary graphical card, so I can connect the second screen also with HDMI? Can someone help me?

Comment: How are these monitors plugged in? Do they use standard AUX in for the speakers or is it carried down the HDMI, etc?

Comment: Updated question: The first screen is connected with HDMI, the second one is connected with DVI. And the screens have a green input for a headphone.

Answer (score 1):

That basically means you need AUX input for both monitors, as HDMI for a PC is not normally audio carrying.

You can of course test this if your PC connected via HDMI works with audio although I very much doubt this.

You basically need a headphone AUX cable to headphone AUX cable as below:

[image]

However it depends on what outputs you have on your PC, if you only have one headphone output then you need a second Sound Card.

What is the PC make and Model? I can try to help further.

Comment: I have a headphone output on the front of my pc and on the back also a green aux output..

Comment: You will most likely find the output on the front will cut off the back one, this is so you can have speakers in the back and plug in headphones to use them... The green AUX output may work you will need to plug in monitor in the headphone out on the back and one in the AUX then you will need to find software that allows you to switch what channel it comes out of, if its video then I know VLC has this function... If that doesnt work then you need another soundcard...

Comment: Wondering if this will work: http://www.tones.be/product/ew3751-usb-audio-blaster

Comment: Just to add if you do need another soundcard I would just get a USB one unless you are doing anything that requires a 'beefier' device. USB ones are pretty good these days.

Comment: Literally was just writing to look at USB ones :)

Comment: What software do I need when I want to switch audio of 2 firefox browser screens?

Comment: From my knowledge wouldn't be possible in firefox although I'm no firefox expert. I know you can do this in VLC and Media Player Classic quite easily.

Comment: What you can try with Firefox is getting a tool called NirCmd then you can launch firefox via NirCmd and use the command: NirCmd.exe setdefaultsounddevice xxxxxx and then launch another using NirCmd.exe setdefaultsounddevice xxxxxx and one should work through one and another through the other but I've not tested this on Firefox...